# If map output is huge, how local disk will manage it?

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop, if there is no proper storage capacity to store the map output. Then where the map output(If it is huge) will be stored?

Comment: You can think about batch processing

Answer (score 0):

If the output is too big compared to the space disk, the job simply fails.